# IPN response coming with delay

Tags: paypal-standard, magento-1.5.1, ipn

We have Paypal Website payments standard in our Magento store.
We are facing below issue with few Paypal orders.
Magento is receiving IPN from Paypal and changing order statuses which are not expected.
Please see attached screen-shot.
Also Magento admin-end is showing IPN is received twice.
But in paypal logs in Magento I cannot see any unusual thing or any error message.

what can be the probable issue here and how this can be fixed. Any help will be appreciated.
[image]

Comment: Is your PayPal account used in more than one application eg multiple websites?

Comment: @Goose84 No, we are using it for single website only.

Comment: I did have a similar issue but mine was connected to the account being used in multiple places. All I can suggest is that you Make sure you have checked the notification URL in PayPal is correct